# pipefail for Process substituion

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script using `errexit` and `pipefail`:

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
diff $FILE <($COMMAND)
```

If `$COMMAND` fails setting `errexit` does not terminate `diff`. In case of an error `diff` produces an patch file as if the output of `$COMMAND` would have been empty.

How can I terminate `diff` generating an error if `$COMMAND` has failed?

Comment: Don't use process substitution. Use `var=$(COMMAND)` and then `diff "$FILE" <(printf '%s' "$var")` or similar. `set -e` is a controversial issue because it has, as you've just found, somewhat surprising behaviors in many "edge" cases. See [Bash FAQ 105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and search "error handling" [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) for a bit more.

Comment: @EtanReisner It is common to bash `errexit` (lol) but I am not sure if `errexit` is the problem. I looks to me as if an analogue to `pipefail` for process substitutions is missing.

Comment: The problem is that you are expecting `errexit` to catch the failure from `$COMMAND` and kill your script but it isn't doing that because it isn't reliable in that way. `diff` operates on empty files just fine that isn't an error to `diff` (and I don't think you can make it think it is though you can post-diff check that if you want). The shell doesn't *have* the exit status of `$COMMAND` in this case. Though if it can get it then, in theory, there could be a `procsubfail` or similar which would let you check its exit status manually after `diff` completes, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons to use a temporary file here:

1. It makes catching the error from `$COMMAND` easier.
2. It allows `diff`, if necessary, to reread part of the file.

---

```
trap 'rm file2' EXIT
if $COMMAND > file2; then
    diff "$FILE" file2
else
    exit 1
fi
```